# To get the distinct values from two tables

Tags: sql-server

TABLE_1

```
ID   NAME
-------------
1    CAR
2    ANIMAL
5    ROCK
```

TABLE_2

```
ID   NAME
-------------
1    GRASS
2    ROCKET
3    STONE
4    DOG
```

I want my query to return unique ID values from both tables:

```
ID
---
3
4
5
```

Comment: You've told us what you want, but what is your question? What about what you've tried isn't working (and show us said attempt(s)).

Comment: You need to use UNION

Comment: Why do your desired results not include `5`?

Comment: @MartinSmith sorry i have edited the question

Comment: What happened to `1` and `2`?

Comment: @SurajKumar i want 3, 4, 5

Comment: Then explain what you are *actually* after in your question. Stop changing your requirements and not telling us them.

Comment: @Larnu 1 and 2 are repeated in second table that why i dont want them.

Comment: @Larnu You are correct I have seen several times a user ask question and after answering they change their requirement. In this case the logic has not been explained by the OP.

Comment: @Larnu sorry for that from next time i will take care about it.Thanks for correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
select ID from TABLE_1 where Id not in (select ID from TABLE_2)
UNION
select ID from TABLE_2 where Id not in (select ID from TABLE_1)
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c1ec8/11)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the

**Union Operator**

The Union Operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more Select statements.

```
Select table1.Id from TABLE_1
union
Select table2.Id from TABLE_2
```

Here is the [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp).

To get the uncommon result from the both table you can use the below query.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Id INT)
CREATE TABLE Table2 (Id INT)

INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES (1)
    ,(2)
    ,(5)

INSERT INTO Table2
VALUES (1)
    ,(2)
    ,(3)
    ,(4)

SELECT Isnull(Table1.Id, Table2.Id)
FROM Table1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.Id
WHERE Table1.id IS NULL
    OR Table2.id IS NULL
```

Here is the [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b56a09c9fb5b97e74e6cf16907dc7879).

You can also use the below method.

```
Select Id 
 From (
        Select Id from Table1
        Union All
        Select Id from Table2
      ) A
 Group By Id
 Having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Sorry suraj i have edited the question please have a look

Comment: @Star_Dust Check my edited answer.

Comment: can u tell me why A was used there

Comment: @Star_Dust The output of the query is considered as a table of name A here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `FULL JOIN` :

```
SELECT ISNULL(t1.id, t2.id) AS U_ID
FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     t2
     ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE (t1.id IS NULL OR t2.id IS NULL)
ORDER BY U_ID;
```